# How can one use ILIKE with pd.read_sql_query in Python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, relational-database

I am connecting to a database and am using

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ILIKE '%something%' LIMIT 10', engine)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "ILIKE"
```

Is there any way I can use `ILIKE '%something%'` while also using `pd.read_sql_query()`?

Comment: How about `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(column) LIKE '%something%' LIMIT 10"`

Comment: Wait actually your problem is probably the quotes. Are you using single quotes in both places? Try changing the outer quotes to double quotes: `pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ILIKE '%something%' LIMIT 10", engine)`

Comment: Still no. I received TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing